# Intellij Maven hierarchical project view

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

This feature probably may not even exist in IntelliJ but I will try my luck anyway.

One of the projects that I work on has a slightly tall hierarchical maven project strcuture. While I love the "Maven Projects" tab on the right hand side, the fact that it presents the list of projects in a flat list confuses me.

Is it possible to have a tree structure in the "Maven Projects" window? In my case the Maven projects have proper parent-child relationship. i.e, the child projects are folders under the parent project and have the correct names in their pom.

I use Intellij 11.1.3 (Ultimate) and Maven 3.0.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure it is. Select `Group Modules` in the settings of Maven Projects window.

[image: Group Modules]